# How to show other levels in my discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const Random = require('random');

const fs = require('fs');

const randomPuppy = require('random-puppy');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const bot = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const got = require('got');

const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

var stats = {};
if (fs.existsSync('stats.json')) {
    stats = jsonfile.readFileSync('stats.json');
}

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot)
    return;


    if (message.guild.id in stats === false) {
        stats[message.guild.id] = {};
    }

    const guildStats = stats[message.guild.id];
    if (message.author.id in guildStats === false) {
        guildStats[message.author.id] = {
            xp: 0,
            level: 0,
            last_message: 0
        };
    }

    const userStats = guildStats[message.author.id];
    if (Date.now() - userStats.last_message > 60000) {
        userStats.xp += Random.int(15, 25);
        userStats.last_message = Date.now();

        const xpToNextLevel = 5 * Math.pow(userStats.level, 2) + 50 * userStats.level + 100;
        if (userStats.xp >= xpToNextLevel) {
            userStats.level++;
            userStats.xp = userStats.xp - xpToNextLevel;
            message.channel.send(message.author.username + ' has reached level ' + userStats.level);
        }

        jsonfile.writeFileSync('stats.json', stats);

        console.log(message.author.username + ' now has ' + userStats.xp);
        console.log(xpToNextLevel + ' XP needed for next level.');
    }

    const parts = message.content.split(' ');

    if(parts[0] === '-hello') {
        message.channel.send('hi');
    } else if (parts[0] === '-level') {
        if(message.mentions.users.size){
            let member=message.mentions.users.first()
        if(member){
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("RANDOM")
            .setAuthor(member.tag + "'s" + ' level:', member.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
            .setTitle('Level: ' + userStats.level)
             message.channel.send(embed)
            
        }
        else{
            message.channel.send("Sorry noone found with that name")

        }
        }else{
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#985ce7")
            .setAuthor(message.author.tag + "'s" + ' level:', message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
            .setTitle('Level: ' + userStats.level)
            message.channel.send(embed)
        }
```

this is my code + the code from a tutorial on youtube for seeing others and my own level, so when every I type -level, it shows my level in an embed perfectly, but when I do -level @(username here) it gives me an error, i tried everything, please help me. (some parts in here are for other lines of code don't worry about those), there is also a JSON file that holds the xp, level, and the last time someone sent a message, in it, the last message is counted in milliseconds, and for those that say this is very inefficient, well ill take your word for it becasue im still new to coding, and watched a tutorial for this.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @LoganDevine well the error is gone, but the problem is still there

Comment: and what problem ist that? also, where do you get `userStats` from? I assume you derive that from a database?

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca the problem is that when i do -level @[username] it is supose to show the author, [username]'s level: and the Title, level: [level of that user], for the embed, the else's are working fine, its the other parts, and the userStats that is from another line of code for my leveling system

Comment: well, as far as I can tell your `userStats` aren't depending on whether or not you tag someone. So I assume that you always have the same `userStats` object. On the author front it's because you use `message.author` in both cases and thats always the person sending the message, i.e. you. So change that to use the mentioned member instead.

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca thanks for that now my .setAuthor is working correctly, but my .setTitle is still showing the level of the user that sent that message, for example if I did -level @[insert friends user here], it would show there pfp and [insert friends user here]'s level: as the .setAuthor, but the .setTitle would show Level: [insert my level here]

Comment: again, that has to do with your `userStats`. You need to somehow pass the mentioned member to whatever function you're using to get the stats. Currently you always use the same `userStats` no matter what.

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca can you also try experimenting with it ill update the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I "experimented" with it and I think this will be a lot better. I replaced most of your code with something a little more dynamic.

Replace the code inside your `else if (parts[0] === '-level')` block with this. Explanations are in the code.

```
else if (parts[0] === '-level') {
    // create a member variable that is either the mentioned member or the member who sends the message
    let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
    // check if member actually exists, should never activate but you never know
    if (!member) return message.channel.send('Sorry, noone found with that name');
    // create a local instance of the userStats, here named memberStats
    let memberStats = guildStats[member.id];
    // create the embed as you would normally
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setAuthor(`${member.user.tag}'s level:`, member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setTitle('Level: ' + memberStats.level);
    // return with the message sent to prevent other code to be executed afterwards
    // remove the return if you have code that needs to be run
    return message.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Now, seeing as I don't have your database I can't exactly test this but it should work.

Comment: well now ther is an error popping up here is the error
 .setAuthor(`${member.tag}'s level:`, member.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
                                                        ^

TypeError: member.displayAvatarURL is not a function

when i remove the member.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })) everything works, but then it shows undefined's level: as the .setAuthor

Comment: oh yes sorry, those are methods of the `user` property of `member`. I edited the answer, should work now.

Comment: If this helped you, you can accept the answer so other people with similar issues can see what helped you.